# JAVA API returning no results. SQL query run on server does

Tags: java, restful-url

I have a JAVA RESTful API built using NetBeans. I've created a custom method to retrieve data using a field that isn;t the Primary Key. If I run this SQL command on the Database itself, I get data however if I run it via the API I get 0 results.

**Here is the Named Query**:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "KeywordsView.findByCharId", query = "SELECT k FROM KeywordsView k WHERE k.charId = :charId")
```

**The method calling this query**:

```
@GET
@Path("findcharid/{charId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<KeywordsView> findByCharId(@PathParam("CharId") Integer charId){
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("KeywordsView.findByCharId", KeywordsView.class).setParameter("charId", charId).getResultList();
}
```

I've debugged the URL and it is calling and running the URL as expected.

Anything clearly wrong?

Comment: Did you debug your `findByCharId()` method during the actual REST call to make sure that the `charId` parameter being passed in correct, not null, etc.?  This is the first thing you should be checking.

Comment: Yes sorry should ahve mentioned that I have indeed checked that and it is functioning as expected.

Comment: OK...the next question to ask is can your Java code run _any_ SQL query as expected?  If not, then maybe you have a JDBC/ORM problem.

Comment: Yeah other than this one quesry it runs absolutely fine.

Comment: Please also include the sql command and log the charId value in your method.

Answer (score 1):

The charId value is null due to the case not match for the `"CharId"` in `@PathParam("CharId")` with `{charId}` in   `@Path("findcharid/{charId}")`. And this make no result as null comparison is always false.

```
@GET
@Path("findcharid/{charId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
                                       // Should match the case
public List<KeywordsView> findByCharId(@PathParam("CharId") Integer charId){
    System.out.println("charId:"+charId);
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("KeywordsView.findByCharId", KeywordsView.class).setParameter("charId", charId).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: I believe it would still return an empty list, not nothing.

Answer (score 0):

the selected field `k` name is similar to the table `KeywordsView` alias `k` too, not sure but this could be an issue? maybe the when qry executed it generates an exception and that's why you have 0 result?

try to change your query as below:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "KeywordsView.findByCharId", query = "SELECT k FROM KeywordsView kv WHERE kv.charId = :charId")
```

Comment: Good idea but then won't compile and deply. All thrree of thost fields must be the same. It's the same in all other SQL quesries however they all work and this one won't.

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed this. It was in my method, there is a sneaky Capital C at "CharId" where is should be "charId".